# Writing elements as product of normal subgroups

Tags: group-theory

Let $N$ be some normal subgroup of $G$ such that $G/N$ is abelian. For any 
$n \in N, n = g_1^{\alpha_1}\ldots g_k^{\alpha_k}$. One can  write $G/N = Nh_1^{\beta1} \times \ldots \times Nh_r^{\beta_e}$.

**Question :** 
For all $g \in G$,

Is it true that

$$g = n' h_1^{\gamma_1}h_2^{\gamma_2} \ldots h_e^{\gamma_e}$$

where $n' \in N$? Each value of $\gamma_i$ is less than equal to $\beta_i$.

Comment: No you can't write it

Comment: You seem to be writing $G/N$ as a direct product of cosets of $N$? Is this what you mean?

Comment: @Robert Chamberlain.I have edited the question

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Consider the case when $N=\{e\}$ and $G$ abelian

Comment: It will work in that case

Comment: @Print_lol How do you make $G=G/\{e\} = \{e\}h_1^{\beta1} \times \ldots \times \{e\}h_r^{\beta_e}$ ?

Comment: Are u trying to say it is not possible or it is possible?

Comment: On the right-hand-side you have a trivial group, on the left-hand-side you have an arbitrary abelian group. So no, it is not possible.